# Thread that is joined and destroyed by itself

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-ptr

I am encountering a thread deletion issue in my program when using shared_ptr and thread:

```
main()
{
  auto a = boost::shared_ptr<A>(new A());
  m_list.insert( a );
  a->run();

  // DO SOMETHING

  m_list.clear();

  ...
}


class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
   A::run()
   {
      m_thread = unique_ptr<boost:thread>(new boost:thread(&A::thread, shared_from_this()))
   }

   A::~A()
   {
      m_thread->join();
      m_thread.reset();
   }

   A::thread()
   {
      // DO SOMETHING
   }

}
```

According to the time taken by main() or A::thread() in each section "// DO SOMETHING": either the object A is destroyed by the main thread or by the thread created in A::run().
If it is the first case, everything works fine. Otherwise, in the second case, the thread tries to join (join()) and destroy (reset()) itself.

How to avoid this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: `main` must have the return type `int` in c++.

Comment: You should know that `boost::shared_ptr`, `boost::thread`, and `boost:enable_shared_from_this` all have standard analogues since c++11.

Comment: I know, the example is pseudo-code... The question is also valid when using standard analogues C++11.

Comment: How can the thread created by `A` destroy `A` when there are outstanding `shared_ptr` to the instance?

Comment: Not quite sure what your problem is. But, when main returns (on Unix at least) the process gets destroyed along with any threads it might contain.

Comment: You are right, I had over simplified the example. I edited it.

Comment: @user1886318 That clears up one issue. I still don't see how the instance of `A` can be destroyed by `A::thread`, or why that would be desirable.

Comment: Beware that the destruction of `A` is undefined behavior if `run` isn't called. This may be an exception safety issue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux shared_from_this() maintains a smart reference to the object A while the method A::thread() is being called. At the end of the execution, the reference is destroyed.

Comment: @user1886318 Sure, but that reference isn't the only `shared_ptr` to the instance. There should still be one in the list in `main`. So the destruction of the `shared_ptr` in `A::thread` must not destroy the referred object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is not the case if A::thread() is run after the clear of the list. The only shared_ptr is maintained by shared_from_this().

Comment: @user1886318 That's a good point. The problem then is that you are destroying an unjoined joinable thread. Consider having a seperate `join` method for `A` instead of relying on the destructor. You may also want to ask yourself rather `A::thread` really needs a `shared_ptr` or if `this` would be sufficient.